# Define partial index in Sequelize migration?

Tags: node.js, database, migration, sequelize.js

I'm using the following index in my model definition right now:

```
{
  name: 'unique_partner_id',
  unique: true,
  fields: ['partnerId'],
  where: {
    email: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to use migrations instead of sync, so I'm trying to move this definition from model to the initial migration file.

There is a `queryInterface.addIndex()` method, however, I can't find any documentation for it.

SO, how do I define a partial index using `queryInterface`?

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for how to do this in a model and your question answered that for me. So now I'm going to answer this for you! Here's the up function that worked for me:

```
up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
  return queryInterface.addIndex(
    'tablename',
    ['column1', 'column2'],
    {
      name: 'indexname',
      where: {column3: {[Sequelize.Op.ne]: null}}
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me when using an UUID column: `ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = boolean`

Comment: Can you provide an example that does what you describe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `where` querying syntax with operators:

```js
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.addIndex(
    'column_name',
    ['new_id'],
    {
      name: 'index_name',
      where: { new_id: { [Sequelize.Op.ne]: null } },
    },
  )
```

Comment: How is this different? Can you explain? Thanks